# Binding an object to a control

Tags: c#, asp.net, postback, repeater

You'll have to forgive me if this makes no sense, as I'm still *very* new to ASP.NET.

I have an arbitrarily long List of items (let's say it's a list of type Person) which I've figured out how to bind to a repeater control and display the item's properties (eg. the name of the person).

What I'm interested to know is how I can kind of "combine" sections and know where data originates from back on the server-side (that probably makes no sense; I'll try again).
From the code below, when the user hits a LinkButton alongside a Person's name, the HelloHandler will run. But how can can I know *whose* name it was that the link is logically associated with on the page? How can I "get" their name?

**aspx**

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Queue" runat="server">
 <ItemTemplate>
  <div>
   <%# Eval("Name") %><br />
   <asp:LinkButton runat="server" Text="Say Hello" OnClick="HelloHandler"></asp:LinkButton>
  </div>
 </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

**cs**

```
public List<Person> People = new List<Person>();

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){

 People.Add(new Person("Albert"));
 People.Add(new Person("Bradley"));
 People.Add(new Person("Chad"));
 //etc...

 Queue.DataSource = People;
 Queue.DataBind();

}

public void HelloHandler(object sender, EventArgs e){
 //?
}
```

**Edit**

For clarification, I want to be able to get back to the appropriate Person object in the List from the event handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I know what you after, The code below will allow you delete a item from a repeater from the click of a link button.

**EDIT :** In response to the comment I have changed the code to show how to pass an ID back to the command event.

Change your top line to

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Queue" runat="server" ItemCommand="rpt_ItemCommand">
```

and the following line to your link button

```
<asp:LinkButton id="lbDelete" runat="server" Text="[Delete]" CommandName="delete"></asp:LinkButton>
```

Then add the following in your cs

To get an ID of the repeater item, you the CommandArgument, set the ID during data bind.

```
protected void rep_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
      if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item)
      {
           var lbDelete = (LinkButton)e.Item.FindControl("lbDelete");
           lbDelete.CommandArgument = retailItem.Id.ToString();
    }
}

protected void rpt_ItemCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e) 
{
   if (e.CommandName == "delete")
        {
            LinkButton btn = e.CommandSource as LinkButton;

            if (btn != null)
            {
                var itemID = (string)e.CommandArgument;

                //Do Stuff
            }
        }
}
```

This will mean you now have this event fire in the code behind when you click the button in the repeater..

Comment: I tried that, but I need the reference back to the object in the list. I did come up with a solution based on what you've got there though. I'll post it up now.

Comment: The answer now shows how to pass an item ID back to code behind

Answer (score 2):

In this kind of situation, you would use the [LinkButton.CommandArgument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.linkbutton.commandargument.aspx) property. You can set the data for each LinkButton with some data and then pull that data out when the button event handler is called.

Comment: I might have given a bad example. When I said I wanted the name, I kind of meant that I wanted the whole Person object in the list.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what TheAlbear posted, I came up with this in the event handler.

```
public void rpt_ItemCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e) {
    Person p = People[e.Item.ItemIndex];
}
```

I don't know if using the index is reliable though.

Comment: Index is not really a reliable source, I have changed my answer to show how to pass though the item ID.